# bash variables: expanding the values of variables whose names match a pattern

Tags: bash

Let's say in bash I have several variables: POD3_1, POD3_A, POD3_2, POD3_B, etc. Each of the variables names begins with "POD3". Let's say I want to expand the value of all the variables on the command line so that I can use these values in a script:

```
for H in $POD3_1 $POD3_A ...
do
...
done
```

Instead of writing out each of the variable names by hand as shown above (because there are so many), is there a way to do this so that any variable name matching "POD3" is expanded? In other words, a "wildcard" for variable *name*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's curly brace expansion. `{..}`
If for instance, your variables are POD3_1, POD3_2 till 9 and POD3_A, POD3_B, till M, you can do something like this -

```
  for H in $POD3_{1..9} $POD3_{A..M} 
  do
     ...
  done
```

If the variable names are not a sequence, you can use the comma separator -
`$POD3_{1,A,F}`

Comment: This helps a bit, in the sense that it saves a little bit of typing, but I still have to type each of the trailing parts. There's no wildcard to handle this?

Comment: Not for variable names, that i am aware of. You can use wild cards for file name expansion aka globbing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over the output of `env`.

```
env | awk -F = '$1 ~ /^POD3_/ { print $1 }' |
while read var; do
    :
    :
done
```

The Awk script examines each variable name, and only prints it if it matches the pattern.

What you have inside the loop is the variable's name, not its value.  In Bash, you can use `${!var}` to interpolate it; in POSIX `sh`, I imagine you would have to resort to `evak`, or modify the loop to directly loop over values instead of variable names.

This will still somewhat suck if you have multi-line variables, but the probability for a false positive is rather low. (Less so if you switch to looping over values.)

Comment: This is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash version 4, use an associative array instead of having to manage dozens of variables:

```
declare -A POD3=(
  [1]=value_1
  [2]=value_2
  [A]="value a"
  [B]="value b"
  [C]="value c"
)

echo "${POD3[A]}"

for key in "${!POD3[@]}"; do
  echo "$key => ${POD3[$key]}"
done
```